# Exception: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have updated my php version to 7.1.16, now i unable to execute my codeigniter site.There is error like

> Exception: **Call to undefined function mysqli_init()** 
>   /home/public_html/codeigniter_demo/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php 126.It works well with php version 5.4.45 but not for php version 7.1.16

Comment: show what you done,code

Comment: have you installed the necessary php-mysql package?

Comment: @FMK `php-mysqli`, as `php-mysql` is not available for PHP 7.1